# In gas law equations, if volume and temperature are directly proportional, why can't we write the equation as temperature divided by volume?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

In gas law equations, volume, temperature, pressure and amount of substance may vary. In the simpler equations, like Charles' and Amonton's, temperature and pressure/volume are directly proportional. Why are the equations specifically with the temperature in the denominator, like this one with the reciprocal being untrue ( I'm asking a conceptual, not mathematical question)?

$$\frac{V_1}{T_1} = \frac{V_2}{T_2}$$

Comment: We can, and therefore there is a fallacy (a false assumption) in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting! This bothered me long time ago in elementary school. Anyway, later I learned elsewhere that the mathematical convention is to write the dependent variable first in ratio and proportion with a proportionality symbol. Such relations appeared all the time in chemistry and physics.  It is very sad that modern high-school algebra has eliminated entire chapter on ratio and proportion properties (esp. see *invertendo* property*).

So, $$ V \propto T $$ which means

$V$ is a function of $T$, not the other way round. Temperature dictates what the volume of gas will be.

$$ V =c  T $$

where $c$ is a constant of proportionality. Following the graphing convention, this means that one will plot $T$ on the x-axis and volume $V$ on the y-axis. This is nothing but a linear equation with zero intercept when $T$ is in Kelvins.

We can also write,

$$\frac{ V_1}{T_1} =c  $$

and
$$\frac{ V_2}{T_2} =c  $$

Since both fractions are equal to $c$,

$$\frac{ V_1}{T_1} =\frac{ V_2}{T_2}  $$

****Invertendo*** property of ratios tells us that a/b: c/d is the same as b/a:d/c.

$$\frac{ T_1}{V_1} =\frac{ T_2}{V_2}  $$

is also correct. It is not wrong algebraically. Here you don't care which one is the independent variable.

As another unrelated example is Ohm's law:

One can say, $$ I \propto Voltage $$ which means current depends on the applied voltage.

So, $$ I = c Voltage $$

$c$ turns out to be the inverse of resistance $R$.

Comment: "It is very sad that modern high-school algebra has eliminated ..." Has deletion of this topic from the curriculum been universal? I remember attending a weekend course that taught the topic. It was.... not the most interesting subject, but maybe useful. I would guess there is increasingly more to learn as more info is accumulated, and this is covered in passing with other topics. Teaching is riddled with topics that could be taught more deeply to great benefit but aren't, time being in short supply.

Comment: And I learned about rational numbers early on, as I would guess many do. That would be the basis for developing an understanding of ratios.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I think this chapter has been universal for high schools. I am talking about grade 10 (high school algebra). You must have noticed questions like these and dilution problems lately. It reminds of its need. These are all ratio and proportion problems. I you teach, ask your students if they recognize the proportionality symbol. They might not identify at all or call it alpha.

Comment: I suspect the OP might be confused as to why the ideal gas law cannot be derived as T/V = nR/p as opposed to V/T = nR/p . I am not sure about whether it is a question with grasp of algebra, but it might be.

Comment: I think this is functional notation, $y=f(x)$. Dependent variable(s) first. V is proportional to T and V is inversely proportional to P.

Comment: Ok, but I still have difficulty seeing how that aspect has anything to do with how you would relate the ratio V/T to the remaining variables. See also the comments under Poutnik's answer. But I suppose you might be right.

Comment: @BuckThorn, the OP writes "Why do we solve for V/T and not T/V if the volume and temperature are directly proportional? Answers will be obviously be very different". This is obviously *incorrect*.

Comment: I interpret that to mean that the OP thinks the ideal gas law would look differently. I agree that there is a problem there with understanding the algebraic solution of the problem, and that $V/T = c \implies T/V = 1/c $

Comment: Measuring the volume regardless of P and T defines the amount of gas. Adding P or T defines the state.  PV = nRT is actually a description of the internal energy of a [ideal] gas. It says that the energy is a function of the temperature and the amount of gas present.

Comment: @jimchmst, This is a good reasoning. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

The questions in the title and the body ask different things.

We cound write $\frac{T}{V}$ instead of $\frac{V}{T}$, but there is, perhaps unwritten, convention using the cause as the denominator.

The equation $\frac{V_1}{T_1}=\frac{V_2}{T_2}(=\frac{nR}{p})$ is obviously valid only for ideal gases ($pV=nRT$) at isobaric conditions.

Comment: Actually, the question is one and the same. Why do we solve for V/T and not T/V  if the volume and temperature are directly proportional? Answers will be obviously be very different.

Comment: "Why are being untrue" gives the other question different sense.

Comment: @suse You are not solving for $\frac{V}{T}$, you're using three known variables to calculate an unknown fourth, or perhaps the volume ratio from the temperature ratio. Proportions don't care about fraction position as long as correct direct or inverse relationship between variables is preserved.